# Java Swing real-time (synchronization/collaboration) live data updates

Tags: java, swing, synchronization, real-time, collaboration

Hey all I’m new to java so keep that in mind.

I have created a swing application that has a jtable on it. The jtable has 8 columns and a couple rows of data to go with it.

I’m creating this java swing program for a few people and what I am looking to do is provide a live data update to any of them.

An example of what I mean when I say live data update:

Say we have 3 people (herein names P1, P2, P3) running the same java swing application on their windows desktop. User P2 just updated a cell that was located in column 4 row 8. This change is instantly shown on the other java swing applications for P1 and P3 even if P3 or P2 are in the middle of updating a column as well. Naturally all swing programs running all update at the same time so everyone can see the updates data without having to ask P2 if they made any changes to the jtable.

Is there anything currently in java that would assist in doing something like I explained above? Also, I plan on updating this every second so and with that I can see an issue like P1 opening a drop down and about to choose a value but before P1 can do that the table refreshes which closes that drop down so P1 has to click on it again and this would go on and on...

I am currently using noSQL for just a simple database build while I am in the process of making the app. I am planing to run MySQL once it goes into production. I am also using the Eclipse IDE.

A good few references that are pretty close to what I am looking for:

[togetherJS](https://togetherjs.com/) / [Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/collaborative-text-editor-javascript/) / [ShareDB](https://github.com/share/sharedb) / [DerbyJS](https://derbyjs.com/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

So if anyone could help me out with their ideas or recommendations then that would be great!

Comment: All of these things, togetherJS, ShareDB, DerbyJS require a server.  The "JS" is a tip off, it means JavaScript and it runs in a browser.  So the equivalent in a desktop app is to use the network to connect to a server.  Of course, the server has to have an application that allows you to share data, and there aren't any generic "share my data" servers that I'm aware of.  The fix for that is to run your own server.  Good luck.

Comment: Use [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to pull your data from your server.

Comment: Use `SwingWorker` to poll the server; update the `TableModel` in your implementation of `process()`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20SwingWorker%20process).